# Replacing a character string with a letter

Tags: c

Beginner at C here. I've tried searching for this kind of problem, but to no avail, I haven't found anything regarding this problem. So as the title says, I need to change the string with 'x' but my output looks like this:

```
Your SSID is: x
Your SSID is: x
Your SSID is: x...
```

(repeats until how many characters your SSID has)

wherein it should look like this:

```
Your SSID is: xxxxxxxxxx...
```

My code is

```
for(i=0;id[i] != '\0';i++)
{
  printf("Your SSID is: %c", 'x');
  printf("\n") 
}
```

Comment: print "Your SSID is" before the loop and the newline after the loop. Everything in the loop body will be executed for each iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would work:

```
printf("Your SSID is:");
for(i=0;id[i] != '\0';i++) { 
  printf("%c", 'x');  
}
printf("\n") ;
```

Comment: Isn't it more obvious to just use `printf("x");`?

Comment: Yeah, it is..i just make his code work as he said a newbie to C.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output you should do like the following:

```
printf("Your SSID is: ");

for(i=0;id[i] != '\0';i++)
{ 
  printf("%c", 'x');
}

printf("\n");
```